# /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf file not found

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos7, system-administration

I have PHP7, Laravel 5.5 and mysql installed on Cent OS7 at linode.com
Now, trying to install phpmyadmin and **[following this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-apache-on-a-centos-7-server)** . I have ran the command which says `yum install phpmyadmin`

But, after this, it says, Open the file in your text editor now so that we can make a few changes:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

I opened the directory /etc/httpd/conf.d and found that there is no file present with the name of phpMyAdmin.conf

Below is the output of `sudo ls -lh /etc/httpd/conf.d/`

[image]

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Did you get an error while installing phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue as you except I followed [this article](https://www.pickaweb.co.uk/kb/install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-with-apache-in-centos-server/).
When I ran `yum install phpmyadmin` at the end of the installation I got these errors:

```
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-5.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
Error: Package: php-tcpdf-6.2.26-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-tidy
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-5.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I fixed the issue by running these commands:

```
yum clean all
yum remove epel-release
yum install epel-release
```

And after that I installed php-mcrypt to test if it would install and it did. After that I ran the command `yum install phpmyadmin` and it worked fine. Hopefully this will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to RamonRobben's answer, I had to run:

```
yum remove php*
```

Then I installed phpmyadmin again and it fixed all the PHP conflicts.